# What is the data type of the 'data' argument in d3.request.get?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, xmlhttprequest

As an Object :

```
d3.request('get_movies').get({"actors":"Shah Rukh Khan"},function(){
     console.log(arguments);
});
```

As a JSON representation of the object:

```
d3.request('get_movies').get(JSON.stringify({"actors":"Shah Rukh Khan"}),function(){
     console.log(arguments);
});
```

I could find documentation as to what should be passed as the data argument 
https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/README.md

I tried a few and none of them seem to send the query string parameters upon inspecting. Nor does it construct the respective URL

Edit :

I also tried passing a simple string URL encoded

```
d3.request('get_movies').get("actors=Shah%20Rukh%20Khan",function(){
     console.log(arguments);
});
```

Comment: I get a Bad request error

Comment: what is the Request URL showing in network tab?

Comment: Just `/get_movies`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

query parameters should be added to the url:

```
d3.request('get_movies?actors=Shah%20Rukh%20Khan').get(function(){
     console.log(arguments);
});
```